# Get list of sums of many to many relationship with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Sorry for the bad title.  I have two tables with a many to many relationship to each other. Wedding and User (it's an RSVP thing).  I need to get the count of User's for each Wedding.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

```
public class User{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string FirstName{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string LastName{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(8)]
        public string Password{get;set;}

        public List<UserWedding> UserWeddings{get;set;}

        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;

        [NotMapped]
        [Compare("Password")]
        [MinLength(8)]
        public string ConfirmPassword{get;set;}
    }

public class Wedding{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string PersonOne{get;set;}
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        public string PersonTwo{get;set;}
        [Required]
        public DateTime Date{get;set;}
        [Required]
        public string Address{get;set;}

        public List<UserWedding> UserWeddings{get;set;}

        public DateTime CreatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime UpdatedAt{get;set;} = DateTime.Now;
    }

public class UserWedding{
        [Key]
        public int id{get;set;}

        public int UserId{get;set;}
        public int WeddingId{get;set;}

        public User User{get;set;}
        public Wedding Wedding{get;set;}
    }

#As far as I can get...
int[] sums = context.Users
                .Include(u => u.UserWeddings)
                .ThenInclude(uw => uw.Wedding)
```

I cannot figure out for the life of me how to get the sum of people for each wedding.  Any help would be appreciated. Also, good resources for working with Linq would be appreciated, practice or reading.  Linq is killing me.

Comment: am i getting it right? wedding id1, multiple users, wedding id2, count how many users for each wedding? wedding id1, users = 30 (count users), wedding id2, users = 45 (count users)?

Comment: Ya, that is correct.  For each wedding I need the sum of all users that are associated with that wedding.

Comment: use the `UserWedding` table and group by `WeddingId` then count like `context.UserWeddings.GroupBy(m => m.WeddingId).Select(m => new {WeddingId = m.Key, Count = m.Count()});`

Comment: check answer, wondering why the downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, ill just minimize the DTO for easier understanding

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int WeddingId {get; set;}
    public int CountOfUsers {get; set;
}

var attendance = context.UserWeddings.GroupBy(c => c.WeddingId).Select(grp => 
                 new Attendance 
                 {
                     WeddingId = grp.Key, //will be grouped by WeddingId,
                     CountOfUsers = grp.Select(c => c.UserId).Distinct().Count()
                     //added select userid and distinct to count unique users 
                     //attending the wedding id
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: This is perfect. I like the class so that I can reference the wedding id.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In pseudo code it would look something like

```
var wedding_count = context.UserWeddings.GroupBy(x=> x.WeddingId); //Key is weddingId 
foreach(var key in wedding_count.Keys)
{
//work on Key and Count from here
}
```

something like that?

Comment: Tried this and it works perfectly.  Gab Llorico wrote an implementation with a class that also has the wedding id, which works better in my case.  This works great though, thanks a lot, it really helped.

Comment: glad I could be of service, @LeeMorgan